# Unable to modify Hybris B2B Login Page via smartedit

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, b2b, smartedit

We had a requirement to add create custom components and slots in login page for a B2B portal.
But currently we are facing two issues in it.
-If I try to add any component to the slots created in login page.I am unable to add the components in the newly created slots from smartedit. But if the same is added through impexes it works fine. Is there any restriction for login page slots in Hybris B2B accelerators due to secureportaladdon ?

-Also  another issue that we face currently is, while editing the login page via smartedit while changing from draft to ready to sync mode ,the smartedit page is redirected to storefront url with the error refused to connect.

This issue is not encountered in case the user Is logged in and access any page.

-Also we have observed page level sync is not working in case of login page but it works fine for other pages.

Any reference or pointers to the above issue would be of great help.

We are currently using Hybris 2011 version in ccv2 environment. We have seperate instances for storefront,backoffice,hac and smartedit.

Answer (score 0):

1st Issue can be addressed by writing UserAccessRightImpex.

```
$START_USERRIGHTS
Type;UID;MemberOfGroups;Password;Target;read;change;create;remove;change_perm
UserGroup;cmsmanagergroup;cockpitgroup,employeegroup;;;;;;;
;;;;CustomLeftComponent;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;CustomRightComponent;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;CustomMiddleComponent;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;CustomCMSProductSectionsContainer;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;CUstomCMSProductSectionTabComponent;+;+;+;+;+;
$END_USERRIGHTS
```

In above Impex please check which usergroup is applicable for smartedit login.
User--> can have multiple usergroups

Comment: Tried the same. but is is not working fine.Also this issue we are facing for OOTB components like by adding a paragraph component as well in login page.Also we are adding the components using admin login.

Comment: The same components Ootb and the custom ones works fine on other pages

Comment: please have a look of this impex(essentialdataCockpit.impex) in secureportal addon and admingroup and run it.-->I am just guessing